# Who was the child of the first Hokage?

Tags: naruto

We all knew that Tsunade is the granddaughter of the First Hokage, but who are her parents? What are their whereabouts?

The [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mito_Uzumaki) said that *"Despite the seal's strength, it almost broke at some later point when she ([Mito Uzumaki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mito_Uzumaki)) was going through childbirth."*

Who is this child?

Comment: I don't think anything as such have been mentioned in the manga.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name was never mentioned, nor it was ever discussed about Tsunade's parents or origins, other than she being the granddaughter of the First.

In short, we don't know. It's also likely to not be revealed anytime soon, unless the author would include it in a databook or something similar.